# Check how much memory bufferedImage in java uses?

Tags: java, memory-management, bufferedimage

I have a bufferedImage in Java. How do I see how much memory it takes up?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `JVisualVM` in the `bin` folder of JDK (not JRE) and attach your Java app process to it. Its profiler section can extract memory usage of all classes used in the app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can determine how many bytes the image data alone takes up using this:

```
DataBuffer buff = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
int bytes = buff.getSize() * DataBuffer.getDataTypeSize(buff.getDataType()) / 8;
```

The image itself takes up a bit more space for the color model and other bookkeeping info, but for large images, `bytes` will be the dominant term.

Comment: +1 definitely a smart approach. The additional overhead in a BufferedImage is comparatively small, especially since most images nowadays don't use an indexed colour model (which is the only other potentially large piece of data in an image, could be up to 256k in rare cases).

Comment: Why do you divide by 8 at the very end. Does getDataType() return the size in bits?

Comment: @thehanseatic - Exactly. From the docs for [DataBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html): _"Returns the size (in bits) of the data type, given a datatype tag."_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a straight-forward way to figure this out with 100% accuracy down to the number of bytes, without calculating it yourself (taking into account the color model, the size of the image, and other factors).

[You can calculate the totalMemory() and freeMemory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) on the heap before and after allocation, and get an estimate that way. If other objects are allocated (or collected) between your checks, your calculation won't be accurate.

[This discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/201339/Performance/java/Size-Java-Objects) talks about the size of primitive types in the JVM (an object being a collection of many primitive objects), which you can use to figure this out.

[This article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue029.html) give an overview of memory usage in Java.

Comment: How would I go about calculating it myself (the mem usage of the color model and other factors?) Thanks.

Comment: I was referencing the manual way of calculating this, by reading the documentation, figuring out what primitives ultimately composed a given image, and then just adding up the values.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Runtime#totalMemory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory%28%29) and [`Runtime#gc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#gc%28%29) should be able to get you a very close approximation. Example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();Runtime.getRuntime().gc();Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
long totalUsed = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

BufferedImage image = ...

Runtime.getRuntime().gc();Runtime.getRuntime().gc();Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
totalUsed = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - total;
```

Calling `gc` multiple times increases the chance that the garbage collector will actually run, since `gc` is just a suggestion. Calling `gc` in this example ensures that no objects that would have been collected are adding to memory usage.